# using facebook batch request javascript api

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, batch-file, request

Im trying to send batch request to graph api, and getting error in the response for the second request:

```
"{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Missing message or attachment",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
     }
}"
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I use:

```
var opts = {
               message : 'Some message',
               name : 'Post Name',
               link : 'url',
               description : 'The post Description',
               picture : 'url to image'
           };

FB.api('/', 'POST', {
         batch: [
              { method: 'GET', relative_url: 'me/friends'},
              { method: "POST",relative_url: "me/feed", body : opts }
         ]
       }, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
       });
```

Comment: I think you need to authenticate your request in some way when using/accessing certain parts of the FB Graph API. OAuthException seems to indicate an authorization error.

Comment: The first request goes well with no error, the second request gets the error..ow even when I do it in separate API request, it works FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
                {
                    if (!response || response.error)
                    {
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       
                    }
                });

Comment: Found the problem and solution: body field. This should be formatted as a raw HTTP POST body string, similar to a URL query string https://github.com/jgorset/facepy/issues/55

Answer (score 13):

Like Sharon said, you need to put the body field in a url encoded way.

You can do it simple with jquery, like:

```
var opts = {
               message : 'Some message',
               name : 'Post Name',
               link : 'url',
               description : 'The post Description',
               picture : 'url to image'
           };

FB.api('/', 'POST', {
         batch: [
              { method: 'GET', relative_url: 'me/friends'},
              { method: "POST",relative_url: "me/feed", body : $.param(opts) }
         ]
       }, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
       });
```

Works good.