# Synchronize results of 2 facebook api calls

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a table which I want to populate from my JS. Data used for populating the table is achived from following calls:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    FB.api(arr[i].id, OnEventResponse);
    FB.api(arr[i].id + '/picture', {"redirect": false,"type": "large"}, OnPictureResponse);
}
```

Because it's in a for-loop I can't populate table async on `OnPictureResponse` and `OnEventResponse`. Function `OnPictureResponse` has a longer response time and I can't set an `id` on `<tr>` tag because the response in function `OnPictureResponse`  does't contain it... 

 Any ideas how can solve this? I don't know.. maybe a callback which will give me the response from both API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve this is to use promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

I prefer to use this polyfill: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise

...because as soon as i can stop supporting older browsers, the only thing i need to do is remove the polyfill.

**Another (and probably better) way is to use batch requests in Facebook. You can find information about that in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests**

Comment: Yea, I thought about promises but I can't understand how it realy works. Plus I am forced to pass a callback at fb api calls. So my response which function passed to ppromise contructor actually must be set by callback I passed to api call. If you can find a good example for me that would be great.

Comment: we´re not here to program for you, i´m afraid ;) but there are hundreds of very good tutorials about using promises, just use google and you will find a LOT of them.

Comment: I'm here to program (*evil laughter behind the scenes*). Vicu, actually, I never worked with FB API and there can be some easier way (maybe Facebook supports promises, I don't know), but I hope you'll get the main idea - you can wrap to Pomise anything: http://jsfiddle.net/arkhipov/exzgk5fs/ .

Comment: now that you mention it, i forgot that there IS in fact an easier solution with the api, i will add that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for batch.. I also find an example on how to use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933641/using-facebook-batch-request-javascript-api